# Need to change the subnet mask of kubernetes services

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I created cluster using Minikube to install image called Browsertrix that is deployed in Kubernetes Cluster.
when the image is installed it create a set of services to enable access of it outside the Cluster

[image]

when I try to access the browsertrix-cloud-frontend from the browser I got can't reach this page
I figured something out that may cause the problem in my organization, two different Subnet can't communicate with each other,
the subnet of my computer 10.8.X.X
and the subnet of the browsertrix-cloud-frontend is 10.101.X.X as appeared in photo attached
i want to make both in the same subnet i think it will solve the problem

I searched a lot and cannot find clear example of how to do this process, also i tried to access the Cluster using Minikube ssh and curl the ip of the service and pod and get response

used tool: Minikube, Kubectl, Helm(to install the image).

Answer (score 1):

To access applications deployed in a Minikube Kubernetes cluster, you can use various methods, including **NodePort** and **Ingress**.

Here’s what always work for me using ingress:

1- minikube start

2- minikube addons enable ingress

3- minikube addons enable ingress-dns

4- Wait until you see the `ingress-nginx-controller-XXXX` is up and running using `Kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx`

5- Create an ingress using the K8s example yaml file.

6- Update the service section to point to the `NodePort` Service that you already created

7- Append `127.0.0.1 hello-world.info` to your ***/etc/hosts*** file on MacOS (**NOTE: Do NOT use the Minikube IP**)

8- Run minikube tunnel ( Keep the window open. After you entered the password there will be no more messages, and the cursor just blinks)

9- Hit the `hello-world.info` ( or whatever host you configured in the yaml file) in a browser and it should work

Comment: unfortunately, I didn't solve my problem
my steps i followed :
1) configured the env variable for no proxy and proxy
set HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy:80
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://myproxy:80
set NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,10.8.0.0/16,192.168.59.0/24,192.168.49.0/24,192.168.39.0/24
2) Created new Cluster that have service cluster ip range as follow : 10.8.x.x
command: minikube start --cni=calico --servic-cluster-ip-range=10.8.0.0/16
3) Enables all required addons for ingress
4) create the ingress service using yaml file 
5) Tried to access the ingress with ip provided by ingress service